# MODULE_NOT_FOUND not finding files that are there from npm start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code

When I try to run npm start for a nodejs/react program, I'm getting the error:

```
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack:[
'C:\\User\\.....\\node_modules\\@nodelib\\fs.walk\\out\\index.js'
'C:\\User\\.....\\node_modules\\fast-glob\\out\\readers\\stream.js'
...


]
}
```

There are 8 files in total listed. Though when I go to these files' locations in my files, they are there. So I'm trying to figure out why they say module not found.

I'm already tried npm install as well as reinstalling nodejs and those didn't work.

What could be causing this and how could it be fixed?

P.s. Background: I'm migrating a project over from an old computer to a new computer. On the old computer it worked perfectly and on the new one it hasn't worked due to this issue. I also updated to Visual Studio Code 2022 when I was using the older version before.

Comment: Have you checked the versions of Node.js and other modules like npm?

Comment: Yeah, they show up if I do ```node -v``` and ```npm -v``` in the terminal

Comment: You might be having a higer or lower version of node/npm which might be conflicting.